# Python 2.7: Imgur API and getting clear text comments from a post?

Tags: python, imgur

```
client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret, access_token, refresh_token)
for item in client.gallery_item_comments("c1SN8", sort='best'):
    print item
```

This is my current code. What I'm trying to do is (hopefully) return a list of comment id's from that function. It doesn't do that, and instead outputs this.

```
<imgurpython.imgur.models.comment.Comment object at 0x03D8EFB0>
...
```

What I'm asking is if there is any combination of functions from the Imgur api to get a list of comment id's? [API](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code `item` is a `Comment` Object representing the comment itself. Because it doesn't have a defined way of how to print the Object, you see `imgurpython.imgur.models.comment.Comment` telling you the object type and `0x03D8EFB0` representing the address in memory that object is located at. Do not worry, that is indeed the Comment you're looking for.

Looking at the [Imgur API documentation](https://api.imgur.com/models/comment) for Comment, you can see the a Comment has the following properties: `id`, `image_id`, `comment`, `author`, `author_id`, `on_album`, `album_cover`, `ups`, `downs`, `points`, `datetime`, `parent_id`, `deleted`, `vote`, and `children`.

You can access each property by accessing `item.<property>` inside the for loop. For example, if you want to print all the `id`s you can do the following:

```
client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret, access_token,  refresh_token)
for item in client.gallery_item_comments("c1SN8", sort='best'):
    print item.id
```